# How to dynamically create a cache in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jcache

I create a spring boot project use jcache, config like this:

```
spring.cache.jcache.provider=org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider
spring.cache.jcache.config=classpath:ehcache.xml
```

I want to create cache dynamically, my code like this:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var cacheManager: CacheManager;

@RequestMapping("setCache")
fun setCache(key: String, v: String) {
    cacheManager.getCache("test").put(key, v)
}

@RequestMapping("getCache")
fun getCache(key: String) {
    val  v = cacheManager.getCache("test")[key]
    println(v)
}
```

but I can't get cache when cache doesn't exist, I want to create cache dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

I came around the same issue. There are basically two options.

- Either you create and wrap the CacheManager during the CacheManager creation in your Spring Boot Cache Configuration
- OR You use an own implementation of an `CacheResolver` in the `@Cacheable` annotation

```
import javax.cache.CacheManager;
import javax.cache.spi.CachingProvider;

@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CachingConfig {

    @Bean
    public CacheManager extendedCacheManager() {
        CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
        // get the cache manager according your provider you have chosen
        CacheManager cacheManager = provider.getCacheManager(...);
        // wrap it with your own implementation
        return new MyCacheManager(cacheManager);
    }
}
```

Own CacheManager Wrapper

```
import javax.cache.Cache;
import javax.cache.CacheManager;
import javax.cache.configuration.Configuration;
import javax.cache.configuration.MutableConfiguration;

public class MyCacheManager implements CacheManager {

    CacheManager cacheManager;

    public MyCacheManager(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        super();
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }

   ...

    public <K, V> Cache<K, V> getCache(String cacheName, Class<K> keyType, Class<V> valueType) {
        Cache<K, V> cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName, keyType, valueType);
        if (cache == null) {
            MutableConfiguration<K, V> configuration = new MutableConfiguration<>();
            cache = this.cacheManager.createCache(cacheName, configuration);
        }
        return cache;
    }

}
```

For to the other possibility via `CacheResolver`. First you need an own implementation of the interface `javax.cache.annotation.CacheResolver`
and `javax.cache.annotation.CacheResolverFactory`. you can do this in the same class or having separate classes.

```
import javax.cache.annotation.CacheResolver;
import javax.cache.annotation.CacheResolverFactory;


import javax.cache.Cache;
import javax.cache.CacheManager;
import javax.cache.configuration.MutableConfiguration;

public class AutoCacheResolverFactory implements CacheResolverFactory, CacheResolver {

    CacheManager cacheManager;

    public AutoCacheResolverFactory(CacheManager cacheManager) {
        super();
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
    }

    // from interface CacheResolverFactory

    @Override
    public CacheResolver getCacheResolver(CacheMethodDetails<? extends Annotation> cacheMethodDetails) {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public CacheResolver getExceptionCacheResolver(CacheMethodDetails<CacheResult> cacheMethodDetails) {
        return this;
    }

     // from interface CacheResolver 

     public <K, V> javax.cache.Cache<K, V> resolveCache(CacheInvocationContext<?> cacheInvocationContext) {
        String cacheName = cacheInvocationContext.getCacheName();
        javax.cache.Cache<K, V> cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
        if (cache == null) {
            MutableConfiguration<K, V> configuration = new MutableConfiguration<>();
            cache = this.cacheManager.createCache(cacheName, configuration);
        }
        return cache;
    }

}
```

and then at your method where you like to cache the results use the annotation accordingly.

```
import javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult;

public class MyService { 
...
   @CacheResult(cacheResolverFactory= AutoCacheResolverFactory.class) 
   public List<MyExpensiveResult> getExpensiveResult(...){
      ...
   }
}
```